# Angular inline style for each reactive form row

Tags: angular

I have a reactive form array and this is a list which shows uploaded fonts uploaded to server. I'd like to show a preview of the font used **for each row**. The problem I have is it seems I'm not allowed to use dynamic variables within each row. I'm trying:

```
<tbody formArrayName="fonts" cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
        <tr *ngFor="let fontRow of myForm.controls.fonts.controls; let i=index" cdkDrag>
          <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
            <td><div class="move" cdkDragHandle><i class="pi pi-sort-alt"></i></div></td>
            <td><input type="text" formControlName="refName" /></td>
            <td>
                <input type="file" formControlName="fontUpload" (change)="changeFont($event, fontRow)" placeholder="Upload file..." accept="image/x-png" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <style>
                    @font-face {
                        font-family: 'uiFont';
                        src: url({{fontRow.controls.filePath.value}}) format('truetype');
                        font-weight: normal;
                        font-style: normal;
                    }
                </style>

                <div style="font-family: 'uiFont'">This is the text to preview.</div>
            </td>
            <td><div class="delete" (click)="removeFontRow(i, fontRow)"><i class="pi pi-times"></i></div></td>
          </ng-container>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
```

However when I try this, I notice in the  tag, the src line prints out the angular moustache code rather than actually rendering it properly: `src: url({{fontRow.controls.filePath.value}}) format('truetype');`

Any ideas on how to approach this?

The reason why I wish to do it this way, is that the user could upload a different font per row so it could always be changing.

Many thanks.

Comment: Rather than adding the styles for the font onto each row dynamically - I would add a dynamic classname of the font-face in the html - and then have styles in the normal stylesheet to apply the font-face etc of the requested font. That way it is more controllable and neater code. It does mean you need to pre-empt the available fonts - and conditionally load them and and the styles - but its cleaner in the code.

Comment: @gavgrif thanks for the advice. Sadly I can't predict what available fonts there will be. There could be 1, there could be 100.

Comment: I was thinking about that - on the font upload fiunction - you could use that to dynamically generate the styles required and appent it to a style sheet  then use the font-family name as the classname on the elemnet in the html. That way you are still applying a class - and the class has the font specific styling added to the stylesheet dynamically via javascript.